# MySQL - Getting 1140 error ... this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by, but its disabled

Tags: mysql

I'm a bit stumped by this. I've used mysql 5.7x before and I've always been able to fix this issue by removing ONLY_GROUP_BY from the sql_modes in the mysql config. However, today I appear to be unable to do so, even removing it from the sql_modes setting doesn't stop me from recieving this error.

I know what causes the error and I know there is a work around that you can add to the SQL, however I do not have time to fix the litteral hundreds of queries in our application which cause this.

SQLMode setting in mysql.cnf:

```
sql_mode = " ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
```

This is then confirmed by running the query:

```
SELECT @@SQL_MODE;
```

Result:

```
'ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'
```

However, when running the stored proc, it still produces the error:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1140 In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #1 of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column 'schema.emp.company_id'; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Does anyone know why mySQL appears not to recognise that the option has been disabled?

I'm running 5.7.21-0ubuntu0.17.10.1 (on Ubuntu 17.10, not surprisingly!)

Comment: show your query  ..

Comment: The query isn't the issue, its worked fine on 5.7 in the past, it hasn't changed and its why I said above, the issue is with MySQL not recognising 'ONLY_GROUP_BY' has been removed from the sql_mode setting, NOT the query itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, just to double the bizarre-ness of the entire issue, it appears that if you drop and recreate the stored proc (with no code changes, its exactly the same), the issue goes away.

This schema wasn't an existing one and mySQL upgraded over it, I did a fresh install of Ubuntu 17.10 on my machine only a few weeks ago and restored everything from backups onto it.

I'm at a loss to explain the above, I can only presume mySQL caches sql modes when it compiles(?) stored procs. I don't know if it does compile then when you create them, but it's clearly caching something.